# How to set ARSCNView to non-mirroring?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

When ARSCNView is configured as ARFaceTrackingConfiguration, how can it be set to **non-mirroring** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Selfie camera's [matrix is mirrored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63023016/flip-arfaceanchor-from-left-handed-to-right-handed-coordinate-system/63027298#63027298) absolutely correctly**.

`ARFaceTrackingConfig` uses **`selfie`** camera that is [oriented 180 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582930/why-does-arfaceanchor-have-negative-z-position/57632396#57632396) - away from the **`rear`** camera. Such an orientation places a user's face in the positive Z direction. To the right of the user is the negative X-axis. Thus, when combining the scene with the `ARWorldTrackingConfig` and `ARFaceTrackingConfig`, we get an absolutely correct 3D environment.

[image]